# Arduino MKR1000 as Access Point

Tags: mkr1000

I want to turn my Arduino MKR1000 into an Access Point. My code is the following:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>
#define PubNub_BASE_CLIENT WiFiClient
#include <PubNub.h>

WiFiServer server(80);
char ssid[] = "MKR1000";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Creating access point named: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  if (WiFi.beginAP(ssid) != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Creating access point failed");
    while (true);
  }
  server.begin();
  printStatus();
}

void loop() {

}

void printStatus() {
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  Serial.print("To connect, join the network and open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);
}
```

After uploading this, in the serial monitor I get this:

```
Creating access point named: MKR1000
Creating access point failed
```

I'm new to this so I really don't know what's the problem. I hope someone knows what's going on.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hopefully you mean you want the board to function in AP mode for connected clients to exchange messages specifically with it.  Trying to actually make it a wifi access point in the sense of a wifi router is not a viable idea.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101BeginAP) for `Wifi.beginAP()` in the [Wifi101 library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101), which I hope is the correct one - apologies if it's not.

It says that `beginAP()` returns either `WL_AP_LISTENING` or `WL_CONNECT_FAILED`, so checking for `WL_CONNECTED` is not sensible.

Try this:

```
if (WiFi.beginAP(ssid) != WL_AP_LISTENING) {
  Serial.println("Creating access point failed");
  while (true);
}
```